# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==306 (from versions: none)

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, pywin32, requirements.txt

While trying to deploy my django project I am getting this eror:

```
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==306 (from versions: none)
       ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==306
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed`**
```

I work on Windows

The necessary dependencies, including pip, setuptools, wheel, and SQLite3, were installed. The requirements specified in the requirements.txt file were being installed using pip. Up to the installation of the pytz package, everything seemed to be going smoothly. The deployment process encountered an error when attempting to install the pywin32==306 package. The error message indicates that there is no matching distribution found for this package.

Comment: `pywin32` doesn't sound like a good installation candidate for a linux server...

Comment: I made the mistake of trying to install pywin32 on a linux server. I removed it from my requirements.txt file and it worked.